# React Native Socket.IO on a Node.js server not connecting

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io, expo, real-time

I am building a React Native Expo app that needs to use real-time communication using socket.io. I am running a Node.js server on localhost.
Here is my code

React Native - home.js

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:4000");
```

Node.js - index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 4000;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

const http = require("http").Server(app);
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());


const socketIO = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: {
        origin: "<http://localhost:3000>"
    }
});

// Add this before the app.get() block
socketIO.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`⚡: ${socket.id} user just connected!`);

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      socket.disconnect()
      console.log(': A user disconnected');
    });
});

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: "Hello world",
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

For some reason, when I try to connect to the server from the frontend, nothing is happening. How can I solve this so that I could do real-time comminication?

**UPDATED**

I do

```
const socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:4000",  {
        transports: ['websocket']
     });

socket.on("connect_error", (e) => {
        console.log("this is the error - ", e)
       
      });
```

and the console logs  `this is the error -  [Error: websocket error]`

Comment: See if you can verify the client connection is successful and check for any errors following this, https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-socket-instance/#connect_error

Answer (score 0):

home.js

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io.connect("<Your IP>:4000");
```

for ip you need to open cmd (windows) Or terminal (mac)

windows :ipconfig

mac : ifconfig

Comment: Does this mean I cant run a websocket connection off my localhost?

Comment: you can try this "ws://localhost:3000/"

may be it works